# Register for global file drag events in Cocoa

Tags: macos, cocoa, drag-and-drop, macos-carbon, nsevent

I'm trying to be notified when a OS X user is dragging any file in OS X, not only in my app.

My current approach was using `addGlobalMonitorForEventsMatchingMask:handler:` on `NSEvent`, as follows:

```
[NSEvent addGlobalMonitorForEventsMatchingMask:NSLeftMouseDraggedMask handler:^(NSEvent* event) {
    NSPasteboard* pb = [NSPasteboard pasteboardWithName:NSDragPboard];
    NSLog(@"%@", [pb propertyListForType:NSFilenamesPboardType]);
}];
```

This works partially - the handler is being called when I start dragging a file from my desktop or Finder, however it also is being called when I perform every other operation that contains a left-mouse-drag, e.g. moving a window. The issue is that the `NSDragPboard` still seems to contain the latest dragged file URL e.g. when I let off the file and start moving a window, which makes it hard to distinguish between these operations.

TL;DR - I am interested in file drag operations system-wide. I do not need any information about the dragged file itself, just the information that a file drag operation has been started or stopped. I would appreciate any hint to a possible solution for this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After having talked to Apple DTS, this is most likely a bug. I have filed [rdar://25892115](http://www.openradar.me/radar?id=5027980136939520) for this issue. There currently seems to be no way to solve my original question with the given API.

To solve my problem, I am now using the Accessibility API to figure out if the item below the cursor is a file (kAXFilenameAttribute is not NULL).

Answer (score 2):

```
NSPasteboard* pb = [NSPasteboard pasteboardWithName:NSDragPboard];
NSArray* filenames = [pb propertyListForType:NSFilenamesPboardType];
NSInteger changeCount = pb.changeCount;

//when moving a window. the changeCount is not changed, use it to distinguish
if (filenames.count > 0 && self.lastChangeCount != changeCount){ 
    self.lastChangeCount = changeCount;
//your code here
}
```

Comment: Can you provide an explanation to go along with the code?

Comment: //when drag a file the drag pasteboard  contains filenames and  pb.changeCount is changed, now drag a window not a file filenames in pb still contained, important changeCount is not change you use it distinguish 


if (filenames.count > 0 && self.lastChangeCount != changeCount){ 
    self.lastChangeCount = changeCount;
//your code here
}

Comment: This seems to work very well and doesn't require using the Accessibility API. Thanks!